# What's the difference between 2 css selectors (one using > and one not)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was always wondering what's the difference between these 2 selectors:

```css
#someID img
```

and

```css
#someID > img
```

Both of them are effecting the `img` tags that are inside `#someID`.

Any idea what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` indicates immediate nesting. The `img` is an immediate child of `#someID`. The first selector will affect *all* images *anywhere* within `#someID`. The second will affect *only* immediate children.

Answer (score 3):

`#someID img` will select any `img` element under an element with the id of `#someID`.

```
<div id="someID">
    <img href="#" /><!-- selects this element -->
    <div>
        <img href="#" /><!-- also selects this element -->
    </div>
</div>
```

`#someID > img` will only select `img` elements directly under an element with the id of `#someID`.

```
<div id="someID">
    <img href="#" /><!-- selects this element -->
    <div>
        <img href="#" /><!-- doesn't select this element -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` is a direct child selector.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fNHkA/)

Take this example:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper > .one { border:10px solid red; }
.one { height:100px; width:100px; padding:20px; margin:50px; border:5px solid orange;}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="one">
            <div class="one"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the `.one` div directly under `#wrapper` will get the red border.

Answer (score 1):

The second only matches if `img` is a direct descendant of `#someID`, where as the first doesn't care.

Illustrative example:

```
<div id="someID">
  <img .../> <!-- both "#someID img" & "#someID > img" -->
  <div>
    <img .../> <!-- only "#someID img" -->
  </div>
</div>
```